# python json.load exception being passed

Tags: python, json, exception

sorry if this is a simple question, I am new to Python. I am trying to catch the error that my json script might not be formatted correctly.

The code below though seems to post the request and resturns and error:

```
hashId = output["requestId"] # finds what the result id is

KeyError: 'requestId'
```

I'm not sure why it is not printing 'JSON syntax error' and stopping there.

Thanks

```
import json
import requests


def read_json_file(file): 
    try:
        return json.load(file)
    except ValueError:
        print('JSON syntax error')

def returnRequestId(working_file, url, username, password):
    try:
        with open(working_file, 'r') as fh:  
            data = read_json_file(fh)

        requestpost = requests.post(url, json=data, auth=(username, password)) 

        output = requestpost.json() 

        hashId = output["requestId"] 

        return hashId   

    except ValueError:

        print('no request id')
```

Comment: you have to show input file's content

Comment: Because the JSON presumably *isn't* formatted incorrectly, so there is no error to catch. The fact that it doesn't contain the key you're looking for doesn't make the JSON itself invalid.

Comment: sorry if i am being dumb. But the JSON being formatted incorrectly surely means that the json.load shouldn't work rather than it only being realised when the request is post.

Comment: Can you confirm if you `requestId` as key in your JSON file?

Comment: requestId is a parameter that should be returned if the code works. When the JSON file is formatted correctly the code returns hashid. However, I wanted to include an exception that would identify when the user hasn't formatted their JSON correctly. When I do this I get the above result. I was hoping that the first try/except would see this problem and print that the JSON is incorrect

Comment: If it's about the key then...shouldn't be `except KeyError` instead?

Comment: if there is no `output["requestId"]` it only means that server didn't send this information. JSON is incorrectly formatted when "there are no 'commas' in expected places". `json.load` doesn't check if there are no fields expected by you.

Comment: The KeyError is because this is now returned rather than the requestid{
  "status": 400,
  "code": "error.invalid.json",
  "message": "Error reading the request. Probably invalid JSON or number format or unknown JSON-attribute."
}